# Routing and path aliases

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have created a module with its routing.yml file.

```
mymodule.dossier:
  path: '/dossiers/{node}/dossier'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'node.dossier_dossier'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

I have created a custom view mode (node.dossier_dossier) and the corresponding Twig template. If I go to dossiers/1/dossier, it works, and it displays the node with the dossier_dossier view mode and appropriate template.

node/1 has /dossiers/my-custom-path as its path alias, which is automatically set from the Pathauto module. If I try to access /dossiers/my-custom-path/dossier, it returns a *Page not found* error.

How can I make this route work for my nodes for both (default and path aliases) URLs?

**Edit**: I should maybe mention why I need that:

- /dossiers/my-custom-path should display the node using the default view mode
- /dossiers/my-custom-path/dossier should display the node using the dossier_dossier view mode
- /dossiers/my-custom-path/abstract should display the node using yet another view mode (I'd create another route for that one presumably)

Comment: Since the path alias already contains the `/dossiers` part of the path, I also tried with `path: '/{node}/dossier'` but that didn't work either.

Comment: The aliases is only valid for the full url, not parts of it. If you want `/dossiers/my-custom-path/dossier`to work, you have to use the complete url as alias.

Comment: @4k4 could you please elaborate a bit more? I don't much understand your comment. Also please see my edit in the question where I explain the goals.

Comment: `{node}` refers to the node's ID, which is then upcast to a node object for the controller. It doesn't refer to any URL alias you may have for the node. To get what you're looking for, you'd need a custom upcaster that searched for and found the node based on its alias

Answer (score 2):

The subpathauto module (depends on pathauto) might help you here: https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto

I have a pathauto alias on my site for `/node/{id}` (let's call it `/node-slug`).  By installing and enabling the subpathauto module, I was able to create a custom route `/node/{id}/locations` which is now accessible via `/node-slug/locations`

Answer (score 1):

Pathauto can't do this, it can only generate aliases to the default view mode.

You can write your own Pathauto module, which generates for each view mode a separate aliases. For a single purpose module there is not much work to do, you only need to generate the aliases and use

```
\Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save($source, $alias);
```

to save them.

The problem is, you get a very large url_alias table.

Or use `route_callbacks:` in *.routing.yml, then define in this callback for each view mode a different route, which calls a Controller, which then in case you have a hit on the route will look up the middle part of the alias and return a redirect to the node in the requested view mode. This is without the static alias table, but may take longer for each request.